# split dataframe cumulatively by variable level

Tags: r

With a df like this:

```
x=data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), val=c(1,2,3,2,3,4,1,3,0))
```

I want to get output like this:

```
[[1]]
  id val
1  1   1
2  1   2
3  1   3

[[2]]
  id val
1  1   1
2  1   2
3  1   3
4  2   2
5  2   3
6  2   4

[[3]]
  id val
1  1   1
2  1   2
3  1   3
4  2   2
5  2   3
6  2   4
7  3   1
8  3   3
9  3   0
```

where the df is split into a list of as many dataframes as there are levels of the splitting variable, i.e. id.  Each dataframe should start at the first level and include all rows up to each successive level.

I can do this with a loop:

```
out<-NULL
for(i in 1:3){
 out[[i]] <- x[x$id<=i,]
}
out
```

However, is there a simpler method using e.g. `split` that I am overlooking? Ideally a one liner.

Comment: Just turning your for loop into an `lapply`: `lapply(sort(unique(x$id)), function(i) x[x$id <= i, ])`. Basically the same thing. `split` depends on coercing something to a factor, and factor levels will be mutually exclusive, so I don't think you're missing anything obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in base R with `split` and `Reduce` using the accumulate=TRUE argument. split is used to split the data.frame into a list of data.frames by by ID. `Reduce` is applies `rbind` to each list element and adding the accumulate=TRUE successively combines the data.frames in the list.

```
Reduce(rbind, split(x, x$id), accumulate=TRUE)
[[1]]
  id val
1  1   1
2  1   2
3  1   3

[[2]]
  id val
1  1   1
2  1   2
3  1   3
4  2   2
5  2   3
6  2   4

[[3]]
  id val
1  1   1
2  1   2
3  1   3
4  2   2
5  2   3
6  2   4
7  3   1
8  3   3
9  3   0
```

Comment: perfect! didn't know about `accumulate`